# Show that the number sequence $A+B$ has number limit $P+Q$

Tags: calculus

This is the definition od sequential limit number. The picture is the problem with help needed. I already solved that and posted picture followed this post. But my Prof said from step 4 made no senses. Anyone can help? I appreciate that.
[This is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BA4pR.jpg)

[My solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwA11.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Your step 4 is hard to make sense of, first of all because it is hard to
see which parts of it are meant to be read and which parts are crossed out
and are not to be read; but secondly because there are a lot of "ifs" and "such thats" with no clear logical connection between the different phrases there. (I don't think what is written there is an English sentence.)

But I think you go wrong at the very start of your step 3.
When you apply the definition of a sequential limit number to
$P+Q$, you must show that it satisfies the definition of
a sequential limit number for any arbitrary number segment $S$
containing $P+Q$.
That means *I* can choose any segment I like (provided only that it
contains $P+Q$) and *you* must then show a number $N$ such that
$A_n \in S$ for every $n > N$.

You do *not* have any right to tell me that I must choose the segment
"$S_A + S_B$" (in whatever way that segment is defined in your
textbook or course notes), based on segments $S_A$ and $S_B$
for which you happen to know the existence of
suitable numbers to satisfy the definition of a sequential limit number
for the numbers $P$ and $Q$.

What you *can* do is come up with a foolproof strategy for finding
suitable segments $S_A$ and $S_B$, *after* I have chosen a segment
$S$ containing $P+Q$, such that you will be able to use the definition
of a sequential limit number for the numbers $P$ and $Q$
to show the existence of the required number $N$ such that
$A_n \in S$ for every $n > N$.

The notation and language you are using for "number segment" is different
from what I have seen in other textbooks in calculus, so I cannot
advise you how to work with those number segments. You might get better
answers if you explained how a "number segment" can be represented
and what operations are permitted.
For example, can I construct a number segment containing all numbers $x$
such that $3 < x < 2\pi$? How would such a segment by written?